# GIT: Fork, applying changes, making pull requests @ github.com - any easier way?

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree, pull-request, git-fork

There is a project on github.com and I have a SourceTree on my machine.
I need to fork from the project, apply changes and create a pull-request to merge into the project.

Do I have any better way to make it done, than:
I can click on fork button in github.com, then click on Clone/New at SourceTree to pull the repository on my local machine, apply my changes, push it back to github.com and click on Pull Request button at github.com

That works, however I'd like to know if there is any easier way?

The cons of the way I've described above is that I have to download the whole project every time even if I apply small changes.
Is there any easier/faster way to create Pull Request?

Seems like SourceTree doesn't provide pull requests option.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to download the entire project every time?

Comment: @gravetii New changes mean new pull requests.

Comment: So why do you have to download the project?

Comment: `git fetch` or `git pull` only download the missing commits, not everything. I haven't used SourceTree but I'm pretty sure it use those commands internally.

Comment: @KurzedMetal, not just internally. SourceTree has the distinction of being a GUI for Git that hides very little. Fetching (or pulling, if you really want) can be done very easily, as it is a first-class action.

Comment: @Haradzieniec, are you trying to *create* pull requests? Or to view others' pull requests?

Comment: @Chris To create pull requests. Thank you.

Comment: Seems like I was able to create new pull requests from the same fork. That means I don't need to fork every time to make pull requests. If I don't leave a comment here anymore that means there were no pitfalls and everything's OK: only one fork is enough to make any number of pull requests. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to *fork* (clone) a new copy of the project for each Pull Request.

Once you have forked, you just need to Pull for changes into your local copy. Doing so, you prevent from downloading the entire project again, but just differences between your previous fork and the current state of the project.

SourceTree has a Pull button for that purpose in the toolbar.